# Why is the age limit of 45 on HPV vaccine?

Tags: vaccination, hpv

[https://www.mskcc.org/news/think-you-re-too-old-get-hpv-vaccine-prevent-cancer-maybe-not#:~:text=Now%2C%20men%20and%20women%20up,people%20in%20their%20mid%2D40s](https://www.mskcc.org/news/think-you-re-too-old-get-hpv-vaccine-prevent-cancer-maybe-not#:%7E:text=Now%2C%20men%20and%20women%20up,people%20in%20their%20mid%2D40s).

> Over the years, researchers have learned more about when people should get the HPV vaccine. It was originally approved for females ages 9 through 26. Then the U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) recommended both females and males get vaccinated up to age 26. However, people up to age 45 can get vaccinated.

Are those who are more sexually active and have more partners easier to contract HPV than those who are less?

Is HPV vaccine likely more effective on those who are less sexually active and have less partners than those who are more?

An older person doesn't necessarily have a lot of sexual activities and a lot of partners. Why is the age limit of 45 on HPV vaccine?

Does HPV vaccine work for those above 45 including men and women?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why the page you link to is not answering these questions for you? It seems pretty clear and directed at a general audience.

Comment: "people up to age 45 can get vaccinated" is not answering why people over 45 cannot.

Comment: Did you see the section "Do you envision the HPV vaccine age limit will increase in the future so that more people can get vaccinated?" - that's the part most relevant for over 45, though the other sections are also helpful in understanding how the HPV vaccine works.